Is there any way in nest js microservice to get ExecutionContext through request scoped provider?
I want a service that can get ExecutionContext  just like we get request object from request scoped providers.
i want something similar to this for ExecutionContext
@Injectable({ scope: Scope.REQUEST })
export class RequestService {
  constructor(@Inject(REQUEST) private request: Request) {}

  getRequest(): Request{
    return this.request;
  }

}


you can leverage Nest's built-in ExecutionContext provided by the @nestjs/common package. unlike the REQUEST token which provides access to the HTTP request object in request-scoped providers, there is not a built-in token for accessing the ExecutionContext.
but you can create a service that provides access to the ExecutionContext by injecting the ExecutionContext directly into your service's constructor.
import { Injectable, ExecutionContext } from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class ExecutionContextService {
  constructor(private readonly executionContext: ExecutionContext) {}

  getExecutionContext(): ExecutionContext {
    return this.executionContext;
  }
}


It doesn't work for me : Error: Nest can't resolve dependencies of the ExecutionContextService (?). Please make sure that the argument Object at index [0] is available in the UtilsModule context.
